# How can you unit test for a correct configuration of a complex TypeToken?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, gson, guava

I have some service code that uses generics and TypeTokens to deserialize JSON. The service is needed to deserialize a complex TypeToken that keeps its generic parameters type.

Here is the code that creates it:

```
<T extends IPolicy> TypeToken<PolicyWrapper<T>> makePolicyWrapperTypeToken(Class<T> policyClass) {
    TypeToken<T> policyTypeToken = TypeToken.of(policyClass);
    return new TypeToken<PolicyWrapper<T>>() {}
        .where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, policyTypeToken);
  }
```

It appears that the TypeToken isn't working correctly because I get a class cast error from GSON.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap 
cannot be cast to com.myStuff.IPolicy
```

It looks like I have it right when debugging. The toString() function shows that it knows its generic type parameter:

```
com.myStuff.PolicyWrapper<com.myStuff.PolicyImpl>
```

Finally, I have a unit test. It passes but it doesn't test the generic type parameter. I test the rawType() of the TypeToken and get the correct class but I'm not sure how to test its generic type.

```
@Test
 public void makePolicyWrapperTypeToken() throws NoSuchMethodException {

    TypeToken<?> wrapperToken = makePolicyWrapperTypeToken(PolicyImpl.class);
    assertEquals(wrapperToken.getRawType(), PolicyWrapper.class);

     //the getContent returns a list but it needs the generic type tested
     TypeToken<?> contentToken = wrapperToken.resolveType(PolicyWrapper.class.getMethod("getContent").getGenericReturnType());
     assertEquals(contentToken.getRawType(), List.class);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears that the TypeToken isn't working correctly because I get a class cast error from GSON.
>   `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.myStuff.IPolicy`

Not really. It looks like Gson, in your case, does not receive enough type information while deserialization. `LinkedTreeMap` is an internal Gson map implementation Gson uses to deserialize objects of unknown types with arbitrary structure by default. It may happen, for example, if generic classes parameterization information is lost/erased for some reason. For example, `private final List<IPolicy> list;` can be processed by tools like ProGuard so it may become `private final List list;` unless `-keepattributes Signature` is used -- generally speaking it's legit Java code, but Gson does not have enough type information and uses `LinkedTreeMap`. And this what you should get once trying to assign such a list element to a `IPolicy` reference. Another scenario is `typeToken.getRawType()` instead of `type.getToken()`: raw types do  not contain parameterization info, so `new TypeToken<List<IPolicy>>(){}.getRawType()` is just a `List.class` -- still no information on elements type that makes Gson to use the default strategy.

> the getContent returns a list but it needs the generic type tested

Just use `TypeToken.getType()` that returns `java.lang.reflect.Type` that is the base interface for all types. Parameterized generic types are represented with `ParameterizedType` that provides more information on the type parameterization unlike the more general `Type` does, and this information can be built with type tokens as well. So, the following assertion is true:

```java
// not really necessary, but just for the demonstration purposes:
assertTrue(contentToken.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType);
// this is enough:
assertEquals(new TypeToken<List<PolicyImpl>>() {}.getType(), contentToken.getType());
```